# How to get Token Securely using jQuery Client

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I put a logic in place for accessing web api using token based authentication. I am planning to build token issue server like the one defined here:http://lbadri.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/simple-web-token-swt-as-oauth-2-0-bearer-token-for-asp-net-web-api/

But I stuck at one point that, how can I retireve the token from the server securely using jQuery clients. In order to get tokens, I have to pass User Credential, at the same time, I don't want the user to enter credential for accessing api. How is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: You could insert the token in to the page (or a cookie) when the page is generated server-side. At that point you know the user credentials. We update our user tokens on every server page-refresh and store the token in the ASP user table for subsequent webapi calls to check. In the page it is simply stored an encoded hidden setting (anywhere in the page your jQuery can find it to pass pack). We also edited our webapi route mapping to always expect a token in request urls.

Comment: It is to inform you that, my website is open for all users. It does not have register/login process. I just want to make my web api secure. So, that user can not access them separately by just simply put the resource url of the api in the browser address bar.

Comment: In that case you don't need tokens. Just check the *referring* URL and only allow requests from your domain. That is how some websites stop images being deep-linked. Use `Request.UrlReferrer` or 'Request.ServerVariables["http_referer"]'. If that does not work you can share session data between you webpages and your webapi calls.